# python argparse help message, disable metavar for short options?

Tags: python, argparse

I want to construct a argparser help message that looks like:

```
-i, --input=INPUT    help for input
-o, --output=output  help for output
```

My current code:

```
arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser
arg_parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', dest='input', metavar='=INPUT', help='help for input')
arg_parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', dest='output', metavar='=OUTPUT', help='help for output')
arg_parser.print_help()
```

is giving me

```
-i =INPUT, --input =INPUT    help for input
-o =INPUT, --output =output  help for output
```

I just want to know how to get rid of the things in between short and long options.

Comment: There is no way to do this using the default help formatters; you'd have to write a customer help formatter to accomplish this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Don't show long options twice in print_help() from argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275023)

asks essentially the same thing.  If you are not up to writing your own HelpFormatter subclass (it probably needs to change one method), you need to play with the existing formatting tools - help, metavar, and description.

Here also
[argparse help without duplicate ALLCAPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642692)

and
[How do I avoid the capital placeholders in python's argparse module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968188)

For that 88275023 question I worked out (but didn't post) this Formatter class.  The change is near the end

```
class CustomFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    def _format_action_invocation(self, action):
        if not action.option_strings:
            metavar, = self._metavar_formatter(action, action.dest)(1)
            return metavar
        else:
            parts = []
            # if the Optional doesn't take a value, format is:
            #    -s, --long
            if action.nargs == 0:
                parts.extend(action.option_strings)

            # if the Optional takes a value, format is:
            #    -s ARGS, --long ARGS
            # change to 
            #    -s, --long ARGS
            else:
                default = action.dest.upper()
                args_string = self._format_args(action, default)
                for option_string in action.option_strings:
                    #parts.append('%s %s' % (option_string, args_string))
                    parts.append('%s' % option_string)
                parts[-1] += ' %s'%args_string
            return ', '.join(parts)
```

Comment: `metavar = ' ' ` gives `-i , --input ` (not the whitespace), while `metavar = '\b ' ` gives `-i, --input`

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in a comment of the accepted answer, following parameter was enough for me.

```
metavar='\b'
```

Comment: I recommend using this if the argument option in question is going to be `required=True` - if you use `metavar=''`, you'll get an `AssertionError`.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter custom formatter version:

```py
import argparse


class HelpFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    def _format_action_invocation(self, action: argparse.Action) -> str:
        formatted = super()._format_action_invocation(action)
        if action.option_strings and action.nargs != 0:
            formatted = formatted.replace(
                f" {self._format_args(action, self._get_default_metavar_for_optional(action))}",
                "",
                len(action.option_strings) - 1,
            )

        return formatted
```

Example output:

```bash
app@01d3adfb794b:/usr/local/src/app$ app database --help
Usage: app database [-h] [-s] [-d] [-b [NAME]]

Options:
  -h, --help           Show this help message and exit
  -s, --sync           Manually sync the database with the services
  -d, --dump           Dump the database as JSON to the STDOUT
  -b, --backup [NAME]  Generate and store a database backup (default: %timestamp%.bak)
```